# Using server tags to display text on the Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page where I have below code:

```
    <div class="Version">
        <label><%System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();%></label>                        
    </div>
```

But this doesn't end up with the version information on the final rendered page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your are missing an equal sign after `<%`:

```
<div class="Version">
    <label><%=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();%></label>                        
</div>
```